# Binary decision tree in Scikit Learn

Tags: decision-tree

i have a simple question that i didn't understand:

Why decision tree in Scikit Learn is Binary tree instead of n-ary tree?

Anyone knows the answer? Please tell me, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This is better suited for the cross-validated site, but the answer is simplicity. Any decision tree simply partitions space with leaf nodes being data and assignment being a function of that data, typically majority in case of classification and empirical average in case of regression.

However, every decision tree can be converted into a binary decision tree. Intuitively, if you have a rule at level 1 like ( X1 < 1 AND X2 > 10) then this can be converted into a two-level run by shifting one part of the predicate downward.

It is much simpler to train binary decision tree than n-ary because of the combinatorial explosion that takes place. Instead of randomly picking a splitting variable and then optimizing over that field (1-d optimization) N-ary trees must select a subset of variables and optimize over that set.